# Gallery images very big in size using html

Tags: html, css, django

Is there a way to make these images smaller? and fit into a box? I followed according to a tutorial and images are bigger. This is zoomed out to 25% view. I'm looking for a way to resize the images to fit into the gallery like view, in the tutorial, the person ended up with a perfect gallery type output unlike me xd .This is for a django project and thanks in advance :)

html code:

```
{% extends 'portofolio/base.html' %}
{% load static %}
{% block content %}

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lightbox2/2.8.2/css/lightbox.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static "portofolio/css/photogallery.css" %}">
    <body>
        <h1 style="margin-top: 70px;">Image Gallery</h1>
        <div id="jLightroom" class="jlr">
            <a href="{% static "portofolio/images/1.jpg" %}" data-lightbox="lb1" class="jlr_item">
                <img src="{% static "portofolio/images/1.jpg" %}">
            </a>

            <a href="{% static "portofolio/images/2.jpg" %}" data-lightbox="lb1" class="jlr_item">
                <img src="{% static "portofolio/images/2.jpg" %}">
            </a>

            <a href="{% static "portofolio/images/3.jpg" %}" data-lightbox="lb1" class="jlr_item">
                <img src="{% static "portofolio/images/3.jpg" %}">
            </a>

            <a href="{% static "portofolio/images/4.jpg" %}" data-lightbox="lb1" class="jlr_item">
                <img src="{% static "portofolio/images/4.jpg" %}">
            </a>

            <a href="{% static "portofolio/images/5.jpg" %}" data-lightbox="lb1" class="jlr_item">
                <img src="{% static "portofolio/images/5.jpg" %}">
            </a>

            <a href="{% static "portofolio/images/6.jpg" %}" data-lightbox="lb1" class="jlr_item">
                <img src="{% static "portofolio/images/6.jpg" %}">
            </a>

            <a href="{% static "portofolio/images/7.jpg" %}" data-lightbox="lb1" class="jlr_item">
                <img src="{% static "portofolio/images/7.jpg" %}">
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
    </body>
    <script src="{% static 'portofolio/js/jquery.min.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'portofolio/js/imagesloaded.pkgd.min.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'portofolio/js/lightbox.min.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'portofolio/js/jquery.lightroom.js' %}"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $("#jLightroom").lightroom({
            image_container_selector: ".jlr_item",
            img_selector: "img.jlr_img",
            img_class_loaded: "jlr_loaded",
            img_space: 5,
            img_mode: 'min',
            init_callback: function (elem) {
                $(elem).removeClass("gray_out")
            }
        }).init();
    </script>

{% endblock %}
```

css code:

```
.jlr {
    font-size: 0;
}

.jlr div {
    font-size: 1rem;
    display: inline-block;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 10px;
}

.jlr div img {
    height: 100px;
    opacity: 0;

}

.jlr img.jlr_loaded {
     -webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease-in;
    -moz-transition: opacity 1s ease-in;
    -o-transition: opacity 1s ease-in;
    -ms-transition: opacity 1s ease-in;
    transition: opacity 1s ease-in;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Luckly i was doing something like this and i used grid , it actually helped me to put the images beside each other in one line in a specific box just like in the photo below, you can open the link below the code and see the output.
[Grid box for images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6rkbs.jpg)

> HTML:

```html
    <div class='l-grid'>
      <div class='c-project'>
        <img src='./images/fulls/01.jpg'>
        <div>
          <h4>Tower</h4>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class='c-project'>
        <img src='./images/fulls/02.jpg'>
        <div>
          <h4>Water fall</h4>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class='c-project'>
        <img src='./images/fulls/03.jpg'>
        <div>
          <h4>River</h4>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class='c-project'>
        <img src='./images/fulls/04.jpg'>
        <div>
          <h4>Sea</h4>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class='c-project'>
        <img src='./images/fulls/06.jpg'>
        <div>
          <h4>Beautiful face</h4>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

> CSS:

```css
.l-grid {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(280px, 1fr));
    grid-gap: 0.5rem; /*Here you can control the spacing between the images*/
}
.c-project img {
    width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `width` and `height` attribute to resize your image.

```
<img src="{% static "portofolio/images/7.jpg" %}" width="Your preferred width" height="Your preferred height">
```

To position images, you can use `margin` attributes:

```
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Test website </title>
   </head>

   <style>
      #test {margin-left: 70px;
            margin-top: 80px}
   </style>

   <body>
      <img id="test" src="test image.png"/>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I was very much aware of `width` and `height` of `<img>` tags, my question was about positioning images, which would also fix the size in grid, I guess.

Comment: @CoolCloud: You can position images with the help of `margin` attributes. You can check my updated answer.

Comment: I have no way to test this code out, it was months ago and I left HTML and this project ever since, and to fix this I used flexbox for placing images in grid CSS was the solution.